# How to prevent Google Hangouts Chrome extension from popping up for other users of the same Chrome installation?

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts

My wife's laptop has Chrome installed. She uses it under her Chrome username. I sometimes use it with my Chrome username. Since installing the Google Hangouts extension on my Chrome account (on my own laptop), she now gets my Hangouts popups on her computer when using Chrome under her username.

This seems like a glitch in how the Hangouts extension interacts with multiple Chrome users. Is there a way to prevent this presumably unintended behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Sign out of your Hangout session on your wife's laptop.

1. Open Hangouts from the Hangouts Chrome extension
2. Click the dropdown menu (the small triangle on the right, just below of the X that close the Hangouts Conversation List window).

[image: Top of Hangouts Conversation List of Hangouts Chrome Extension]
3. Click **Sign out of Hangouts**

Answer (score -3):

Google -> settings -> extensions -> disable

Comment: Sure, "don't use X" is the recipe to solve all problems with X. This does not actually address the issue.